# Robotium - How to replay recorded tests

Tags: android-studio, robotium

I am using Robotium for the first time and I am using Android Studio. I am able to record the tests, but, i am not able to understand how to replay them, on the device i recorded? Can someone help me with this. I tried to look for answers, but all of them were pointing to eclipse and not Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In the Robotium recorder you have button "Execute test" - just press on it. Other way - using Android Studio Run menu.
Please see the [link](http://robotium.com/pages/user-guide-android-studio) for more details.